# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." NIC4 Library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a module into Python and it keeps failing. The module is cochlear.nic.nic4 (it's for cochlear implant research). I have checked the path a million times and reinstalled anaconda. I am running an Anaconda distribution of Python 3.7.6. The folder C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\cochlear\nic\nic4 contains an **init**.py as well as _nic4_37_64.pyd. The init file does seem to be constructing the name correctly to find the proper pyd file. Also, sys.path includes the folder. See below the **init**.py file from NIC4. When I run "import cochlear" or "import cochlear.nic" those return no error. I am running windows 10 enterprise.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

ERROR:

```
>>> import cochlear.nic.nic4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\cochlear\nic\nic4\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    _module = _importlib.import_module(_modulename, __name__)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

__ init __.py:

```
import importlib as _importlib
import os as _os
import sys as _sys

_64bit_suffix = '_64' if (_os.name == 'nt') and (_sys.maxsize > 2**32) else ''
_modulename = '_nic4_%d%d%s' % (_sys.version_info.major, _sys.version_info.minor, _64bit_suffix)
if _os.environ.get('NIC_PYTHONPATH') is None:
    _module = _importlib.import_module('.' + _modulename, __name__)
else:
    _sys.path += [_os.path.abspath(_p) for _p in _os.environ.get('NIC_PYTHONPATH').split(_os.pathsep)]
    _module = _importlib.import_module(_modulename, __name__)
_this = globals()
for (_key, _value) in _module.__dict__.items():
    if _key[0] != '_' or _key == '__version__':
        _this[_key] = _value
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem was exactly, but I realized my default python was a different version. Weirdly it was installed in both but yet inexplicably still didn't work (probably something to do with paths or environment variables set by the installer). But when changed the order of the python versions' paths in my global Path variable in windows (thereby changing which python was default in command prompt) and reinstalled, everything worked fine.

Hope this helps someone...